# How to incorporate ports / sockets for direct tunneling with p2p darknet app

Tags: c++, sockets, p2p

I'm building an app which upon login will connect you to certain ip addresses of which will also be running the same app.

The method of which i believe i should be using is direct tunnelling but as i say im a little new to c++, i have general coding skills, and i have sifted through a lot of forums and sites yet im still very unclear on what the best way forward is to achieve the requirement.

The reason for the connection will be to enable a secure chat, file transfer, and update software auto when connected to the program admin.

All those that have the app installed will once authorised, will be connected to admin client, then from that client all available ip's to connect to will become available to slave clients, this will increase the network size avilable to all users.

so the app needs to be able to handle ports but not via a server, instead it would be direct.

The connections also must ideally be encrypted.

Im kind of looking for what the application RetroShare does, but in text app.

(This is using C++ within Dev C++)

so just to recap, What method should i use to achieve the above?

Comment: So, why should we help you build a botnet?

Comment: For your "direct" connect to work, at least one side of the connection must be publically visible, i.e. they both can't be hidden behind (different) firewalls. Take a look at some of the file sharing protocols (bittorrent being big right now) to get an idea of what you're up against. Good luck!

Comment: As for the secure portion, I'd read up on virtual private networks and the various protocols (ipsec).

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [SDL net](http://content.gpwiki.org/index.php/SDL%3aTutorial%3aUsing_SDL_net) to start with, its really simple to learn if you have never done any socket programming before. 
for a secure connection you will probably want to start with TCP and then once you get the hang of network programming, start looking at other protocols.

Hope this helped! and good luck.

Comment: To be clear, TCP connections are not by themselves secure -- anyone at the ISP could eavesdrop on them, for instance.  You'd need to implement encryption on the data going over the TCP connection; this is typically done using libssh or similar.

Comment: My apologies, i wasnt meaning to say TCP was secure, just that it was a good starting point to move from to something like ssh